# Binding: Worker thread modifying properties

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following code:

```
class Customers : BindableObject
{

    private ObservableCollection<string> _Products = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return _Products;
        }
        set
        {
            _Products = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Products");
        }
    }

    private string _Name = "John";

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }


    public Customers()
    {
        Products.Add("George");
        Products.Add("Henry");
    }

    public void LongRunningFunction()
    {
        Name = "Boo";

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Name = "Peter";

    }

    public void ThreadedLongRunningFunction()
    {
        Task t = new Task(new Action(LongRunningFunction));
        t.Start();

    }


    public void LongRunningFunctionList()
    {
        Products.Add("Boo");

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        Products.Add("Booya");

    }

    public void ThreadedLongRunningFunctionList()
    {
        Task t = new Task(new Action(LongRunningFunctionList));
        t.Start();

    }

}
```

BindableObject implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

I then have in my MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Model.Customers c = new Model.Customers();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        gridToBindTo.DataContext = c;
    }

    private void cmdRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        c.LongRunningFunction();
    }

    private void cmdRunAsync_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        c.ThreadedLongRunningFunction();
    }

    private void cmdRunListSync_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        c.LongRunningFunctionList();
    }

    private void cmdRunListAsync_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        c.ThreadedLongRunningFunctionList();
    }

}
```

My MainWindow has a label bound to Name, and a list box bound to Products.

In the threaded version of both of the functions, I don't understand why I am allowed to operate on a property 'Name' (string) that is bound to the UI in another thread, but I'm not allowed to do the same for a ObservableCollection.

Can someone explain why there is a difference here ?

Regards

Comment: Collections aren't thread-safe.

Comment: Try out using `Dispatcher` to push changes to the UI from an other thread

Comment: Can you post the binding code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObservableCollection is not `thread safe` that's why it can't be modified across different Dispatchers. But you can always override the ObservableCollection to make it thread safe. Look at the sample here - http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/

Bottom line is to raise the `collectionChanged` and `propertyChanged` on the UI dipatcher where collection was created.